# On Windows Vista administrator account how can I make a printer the default for all other accounts?

Tags: windows-vista, printer

I "administer" a Windows Vista Home Premium machine for my brother's family. After installing a printer using my admin account, I then have to log in to each of the other accounts to set the printer as the default. Very tedious.

Is there a a more automated way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a batch file since you can't push any GPO to that computer. I have a good "tuto" for this [here](http://neverblog.net/set-the-default-printer-for-all-users-on-a-windows-xp-computer/)

Comment: Great link! The heart of the tutorial is the command:  rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n”%localprintername%”. I didn't have any luck with the variable "localprintername" so I substituted the actual name of my printer. Also my Home edition of Vista doesn't have a group policy editor, so I used the Task Scheduler to run the .bat file on user login. Works!